# Routing events type (Avro-SpecificRecordBase) to right Consumer from one topic in reactive programming

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I use
spring-cloud-stream:3.2.2
spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:3.2.5
spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams:3.2.5

I want to write consumer kafka in reactive programming. I work with avro schema registry.
In my case i have multiple events type in one topic. My consumer consume all type, but i want to write one consumer per events type.
In your documentation i found some information concerning Routing. In reactive mode i can use routing-expression in application.yml only. But it's not working for me.
Can you help me ? I tried several things, but i don't find why it's not working.
My 2 Consumer consume all events type not specific.

My two consumer:

```
@Bean
    public Consumer<FirstRankPaymentAgreed> testAvroConsumer() {
        return firstRankPaymentAgreed -> {
            log.error("test reception event {} ", firstRankPaymentAgreed.getState().getCustomerOrderId());
        };
    }

    
@Bean
    public Consumer<CustomerOrderValidated> devNull() {
        return o -> {
            log.error("devNull ");
        };
    }
```

my application.yml ( i try lot of simple test)

```
spring: 
 cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        routing:
          enabled: true
        definition: testAvroConsumer;devNull
#        routing-expression: "'true'.equals('true') ? devNull : testAvroConsumer;" #"payload['type'] == 'CustomerOrderValidated' ? devNull : testAvroConsumer;"
      bindings:
        testAvroConsumer-in-0:
          destination: tempo-composer-event
        devNull-in-0:
          destination: tempo-composer-event
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
          auto-create-topics: false
          consumer-properties:
            value:
              subject:
                name:
                  strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy
            key.deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
            value.deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
            schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
            specific.avro.reader: true
    function:
#      routing-expression: "'true'.equals('true') ? devNull : testAvroConsumer;"
#      routing-expression: "payload['type'] == 'CustomerOrderValidated' ? devNull : testAvroConsumer;"
      definition: testAvroConsumer;devNull
```

Answer (score 0):

Routing and reactive doesn't really mix well.
Unlike the imperative functions which play a role of a message handler (invoked each time there is a message), reactive  Reactive functions are initialization functions that connect user flux/mono with system. They are only invoked once during the startup of the applications. After that the stream is processed by reactive API and s-c-stream as a framework plays no additional role (as if it didn't exist in the first place)

So, RoutingFunction mixed with reactive acts as if it was reactive. The expression is evaluated only once during startup and from that point the function is selected and the entire stream is forwarded to that function.

Consider changing your functions to imperative.

Answer (score 0):

I found an uggly solution but it's work. I have an interface EventHandler<?>. All handler class extend this interface. Handler force generic type with the right avro type. I ask Spring to find the right handler.

```
    var beanNames = context.getBeanNamesForType(ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(EventHandler.class, message.getPayload().getClass()));
    if (beanNames.length > 0) {
            var bean = (EventHandler) context.getBean(beanNames[0]);
```